# Best way to use c++ code from R package FOO in package BAR

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am trying to define a function using Rcpp for speedup. The situation is as follows:

- I have a package FOO with a lot of C++ code (my own package and currently not using Rcpp) which have defined a set of functions e.g. foo_a and foo_b.
- In another package BAR (using Rcpp) I am defining a function (using Rcpp Attributes) where I want to call functions foo_a and foo_b.

How do I solve this? Looking a bit in other posts I get that I have in some way to include header files in FOO and use attribute `// [[Rcpp::depends(FOO)]]` in BAR, but I seem to miss some points. Any hints on how to do it?

Best Lars

EDIT: Thanks for the comments I liked Kevin Usheys approach and tried to implement it. However, after some coding I realized that I actually don't need functions from FOO but a  class and its public functions. I guess that I cannot do the tricks you suggested for a class. I ended up putting the source files of the class from FOO in the BAR src dir (not the best approach since I now have 2 versions of the same code). However for the moment this hack work for me.

Comment: Put them into inst/include of package FOO (and set -I../inst/include in src/Makevars; have package BAR use RcppDepends(FOO) -- one copy only, two packages using it.  See what I wrote about RcppXts.

Comment: Thanks Dirk. I will have a look at RcppXts. I did't think that it was possible for a class too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option, in case you don't mind introducing `Rcpp` into package `FOO` - follow along with [Section 3.5 of Rcpp-attributes](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-attributes.pdf) and do the following:

1. Place `// [[Rcpp::interfaces(cpp)]]` at the top of the `.cpp` source files containing functions you'd like to be made available to other packages,
2. Place `// [[Rcpp::export]]` in front of those functions you would like exported,
3. Call `compileAttributes()` in the package directory of `FOO` to generate files in `inst/include` that can then be used by package `BAR`, using `// [[Rcpp::depends(FOO)]]`,
4. Install package `FOO`.

If you have this set up correctly, you should be able to call a function with a template like this (supposing `foo_a` is an exported function from `FOO`):

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(FOO)]]

#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <FOO.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP some_function() {
  return FOO::foo_a();
}
```

Comment: That is actually the same as the other two answers, but gets it done for you more easily :)

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend one of these options:

If `foo_a` and `foo_b` are simple enough, just have them as `inline` functions in headers of `FOO` and put these headers in `FOO/inst/include/FOO.h`. `Rcpp::depends(FOO)` will then include this file when you invoke `compileAttributes` (or perhaps `load_all`) on `BAR`.

Otherwise, consider registering the functions using R's registration model. this is a bit more work, but that's bearable. Writing R extensions has the details. I would suggest putting all the registration logic in `FOO` so that the client package `BAR` only has to use it. For example, I'd have `foo_a` like this in `FOO`'s headers, e.g. in `FOO/inst/include/FOO.h`:

```
#ifdef COMPILING_FOO
inline int foo_a(int x, double y, const std::string& z){
    typedef int (*Fun)(int, double, const std::string&) ;
    static Fun fun = (Fun)R_GetCCallable( "FOO", "foo_a" ) ;
    return fun(x,y,z) ;
}
#else 
// just declare it
int foo_a(int x, double y, const std::string& z) ;
#endif
```

and the actual definition of `foo_a` in some `.cpp` file in `FOO/src`:

```
#define COMPILING_FOO
#include <FOO.h>

int foo_a(int x, double y, const std::string& z){
   // do stuff
}
```

Then, you need to register `foo_a` using `R_RegisterCCallable` in the function `R_init_FOO`:

```
extern "C" void R_init_FOO( DllInfo* info ){
    R_RegisterCCallable( "FOO", "foo_a", (DL_FUNC)foo_a );
}
```

Comment: Of course it is R_init_FOO. I guess you can figure where I got the example from.

Answer (score 2):

The [RcppXts](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RcppXts) package does just that for a bunch of functions from the well-known [xts](http://cran.r-project.org/package=xts) package.

*Edit:* Here is some code from xts.

First, xts::src/init.c does the registration via a dozen or so declarations like

```
R_RegisterCCallable("xts","do_is_ordered",(DL_FUNC) &do_is_ordered);
```

Second, xts::inst/include/xtsApi.h provides a header for client packages with eg

```
SEXP attribute_hidden xtsIsOrdered(SEXP x, SEXP increasing, SEXP strictly) {
    static SEXP(*fun)(SEXP,SEXP,SEXP) = NULL;
    fun = (SEXP(*)(SEXP,SEXP,SEXP)) R_GetCCallable("xts","do_is_ordered");
    return fun(x, increasing, strictly);
}
```

Third, in a client package such as RcppXts we define this (using Rcpp Modules) as

```
function("xtsIsOrdered",
         &xtsIsOrdered,
         List::create(Named("x"),
                      Named("increasing") = true,
                      Named("strictly") = true),
         "Tests whether object is (strictly) (increasing) ordered");
```

which exposes it to R.  We could equally well call the C function `xtsIsOrdered` from C++ code.

I removed the incorrect earlier comment that functions have to conform to 'SEXP in, SEXP out'.

Comment: "Because everything 'happens through R', the functions have to conform to the 'SEXP foo(SEXP a, SEXP b, ...) scheme" No they don't.

Comment: Even better. Is there a worked example somewhere where this scheme is used to exchange C++ objects?   The base example of lme4 and Matrix does not IIRC.

Comment: Rcpp is an obvious example.

Comment: Good point: Rcpp_init.cpp does R_RegisterCCallable, register.h does other side of R_GetCCallable.